# MySQL: Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: mysql, php, percona

I have this error when I try to connect to database using PHP:
`mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch.
Headers:50147 Library:50501`

And this warning in phpmyadmin:
`Your PHP MySQL library version 5.5.1-m2 differs from your MySQL server
version 5.1.54. This may cause unpredictable behavior.`

Packages installed:

> Percona-Server-client-51-5.1.54-rel12.5.188.rhel5.x86_64
>   Percona-SQL-shared-compat-5.1.43-2.x86_64
>   Percona-Server-server-51-5.1.54-rel12.5.188.rhel5.x86_64
>   percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64

PHP version:`PHP 5.3.3`
MySQL: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.54`
OS: `Amazon AMI 64bit`

I tried to remove php and install again, but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed type of database connection in vbulletin config from  `mysql` to `mysqli` and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your SQL shared compat libraries are a version behind the client and the server, as the error message states this can result in some funny behaviour.

Try upgrading the package `Percona-SQL-shared-compat-5.1.43-2.x86_64` to `Percona-SQL-shared-compat-5.1.54-2-rel12.5.188.rhel5.x86_64`, it should be available from the same package repo where you upgraded the rest of your installation from.

Comment: Thanks. Version in repo really differs from that one on site: http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.1/Percona-Server-5.1.54-12.5/RPM/rhel5/x86_64/

Comment: No problem, just as reminder, it's always best to keep the versions for both your libraries and client the same, the server version is not so dependant (but I'm a bit ADD so I keep it in the same ver as well)

Comment: I removed the old one and installed all over again with same versions. Looks like problem with php, because the result is the same.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that... normally I ignore that alert if and only if the MySQL library PHP was compiled in is older than the server version, in that case it should be fine